# What properties of Euclidean Space are necessary for the theory of smooth manifolds?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Lee writes on page 1 of his Smooth Manifolds book,

> This book is about smooth manifolds. In the simplest terms, these are
>   spaces that locally look like some ***Euclidean space*** $\mathbb{R}^n$, and on which
>   one can do calculus

Wikipedia (and Lee) defines Euclidean space as an inner product space with the norm derived from that inner product as $\|x\|={\sqrt {x\cdot x}}$

***Which parts of this Euclidean space are really necessary for defining and working with smooth manifolds?***

At the very least we need a norm to define derivatives and smoothness, but do we really need the Euclidean norm as opposed to any norm?

Also, do we require that there is an inner product associated with $\mathbb{R}^n$ and that the norm is derived from the inner product?

Note, I am only interested in the answer in the context of smooth manifolds (as opposed to considering this question more broadly when defining Riemmanian Geometry).

Comment: Any two norms on $\Bbb R^n$ are equivalent, so you don't strictly need the Euclidean norm.

Comment: You can replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by any Banach space. That thing we call then a Banach manifold. It depends what you want to prove in that setting. A convenient thing about euclidean space is that it is for example locally compact.

Comment: @Lord I am aware of that result. But, I am not sure if that settles the question. Bascially, I am interested in all the results in Lee's book up through Sard's theorem and there dependence or lack thereof on things like the inner product on \mathbb{R^n}. For instance, some proof's in Lee talk about the volume of balls. Is volume invariant under change of norms? How do we define orthogonality without an inner product?